# ASM look at maxStack before instructions?

Tags: java, jvm, java-bytecode-asm

I'm trying to use the ASM library to translate byte code into a different format, which can be done with a MethodVisitor, as with this simple test code:

```
    return new MethodVisitor(ASM7) {
        @Override
        public void visitInsn(int opcode) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%02x", opcode));
        }

        @Override
        public void visitMaxs(int maxStack, int maxLocals) {
            System.out.println(maxStack);
        }
    };
```

One issue is that I only get to see maxStack after the actual instructions – I've tested it, and that is the order the methods are called in – whereas it would be helpful to have the maxStack value available while translating the instructions.

Is there any way to get to see maxStack first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ASM API does not support accessing this information before traversing the instructions.

One solution would be to traverse the class twice, storing the max values in the first pass.

The alternative is to store the current method information temporarily. ASM’s Tree API can help you here. The class `MethodNode` implements `MethodVisitor`, storing all visited artifacts and has an `accept(MethodVisitor)` to visit all stored artifacts:

```
classReader.accept(new ClassVisitor(Opcodes.ASM7) {
    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String descriptor,
                                     String signature, String[] exceptions) {
        MethodVisitor actualVisitor = new MethodVisitor(Opcodes.ASM7) {
            @Override
            public void visitInsn(int opcode) {
                System.out.printf("%02x%n", opcode);
            }

            @Override
            public void visitMaxs(int maxStack, int maxLocals) {
                System.out.println("max stack: "+maxStack);
            }
        };
        return new MethodNode(Opcodes.ASM7) {
            @Override
            public void visitMaxs(int maxStack, int maxLocals) {
                actualVisitor.visitMaxs(maxStack, maxLocals);
                super.visitMaxs(maxStack, maxLocals);
            }
            @Override
            public void visitEnd() {
                accept(actualVisitor);
            }
        };
    }
}, 0);
```

So here, we keep the original `MethodVisitor` as-is but return an adapter implementing the intended modification. It’s a subclass of `MethodNode` recording all artifacts but reporting `visitMaxs` immediately to the `actualVisitor`, then at `visitEnd` it will `accept(actualVisitor)` to visit all recorded information.

Note that therefore, `actualVisitor` will encounter `visitMaxs` twice, once before all other elements, then again within the standard sequence of events.

Answer (score 0):

Max stack calculated for a method depends on the instructions in and the paths thru the method's body.  Hence, max stack will only be available after the method's body has been analyzed.  Refer to sections 3.3.1, 3.3.2, and 3.5 [here](https://asm.ow2.io/developer-guide.html).

You could get the max stack in a separate pass and store it for reference in future passes.  However, modifying the method body may likely invalidate such stored stack info.

Comment: But isn't it stored? I mean, when I generate a class, I have to either supply max stack or make special arrangement for ASM to supply it for me, presumably so that it can be stored?

Comment: Stack map frames available in the code are visited via `visitFrame` before visiting the instructions.  See section 3.3.1 in https://asm.ow2.io/developer-guide.html.

Comment: Stack map frames do not help. First, frames are *not* visited before visiting the instructions, but rather, each frame is visited right at its actual location. Further, frames are only inserted at branch merge points, but there is no guaranty that the code location with the deepest operand stack is a branch merge point, actually, it’s rather unlikely. At the extreme end, methods without branches do not have any frame at all.